# How do I specify a path with white space in it with CMake?

Tags: windows, cmake

Consider:

```
include_directories("D:/FMOD SoundSystem/FMOD Programmers API Win32/api")
```

What's the decent way to deal with a path like the above in CMake?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to escape the spaces with a `\`.

```
D:/FMOD\ SoundSystem/FMOD\ Programmers\ API\ Win32/api
```

Comment: What if the folder is built from built in variable? For instance `set(MY_LIB_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}../../../../../../MyFolder/")`. Then using it in `set(RESOURCES "${MY_LIB_PATH}MyFile.cpp"`where `RESOURCES` is used in `add_executable(MyExe "$RESOURCES")`. It seems that `CMake` doesn't add this escape charterer.

Comment: Adding escaped quotation marks around the variable seems to fix this problem for me, e.g. `set(MY_LIB_PATH "\"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\"../../../../../../MyFolder/")`.

Answer (score 8):

```
include_directories("D:/FMOD\ SoundSystem/FMOD\ Programmers\ API\ Win32/api")
```