# File does not exist

Tags: linux, cmake, root

I am newbie to Linux. I am working on a project that needs me to switch to Linux. I am trying to build a library thats coded in C++. When I pass in the "cmake ." command, I get the following error.

```
CMake Error: File /home/robotEr/Desktop/projects/Robotics/Krang/Path Planning/dart/thirdparty/fcl/include/fcl/config.h.in does not exist.
```

But this file does exist at the above specified location. I don't understand why it is encountering this error despite the file being there. Here's is a list of files and subfolders in that folder when I "ls".

```
$ ls
CMakeCache.txt
profile.h
octree.h
distance_func_matrix.h
intersect.h
data_types.h
distance.h
collision_node.h
collision_object.h
config.h.in --------> HERE IT IS!
collision_func_matrix.h
collision_data.h
collision.h
CMakeFiles/
CMakeLists.txt
articulated_model/
broadphase/
BV/
BVH/
ccd/
math/
narrowphase/
shape/
simd/
traversal/
```

Comment: Are you sure there's a location with `/.../` in its name? That's a very unusual (though legal) directory name. More specifically: What is the **full name** of the directory where you execute the above `ls` command?

Comment: I'm sorry, I included /.../ to hide a bunch of stuff that was in the middle. I didn't know /.../ was a legal path. The full path is here:   /home/robotEr/Desktop/projects/Robotics/Krang/Path Planning/dart/thirdparty/fcl/include/fcl

Comment: x @user: It looks like one of the directories there is called `Path Planning` with a space in it. That is likely to be the culprit -- Unix-based build systems tend to assume that file and path names do not contain spaces, because they often work with space-separated lists of file names internally.

Comment: Can you do an `ls -la` on the directory that file is in and specify the username and group of the user running the cmake command?  It is possible that this is a permissions issue.

Comment: The problem maybe with Path Planning having a space in it. What's the best way to rename this to PathPlanning? I'm concerned if I just manually rename it by going to it, that might break something else.

Comment: Possibly refer to this topic for help:

[How to specify a path with white space in it with cmake?][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328199/how-to-specify-a-path-with-white-space-in-it-with-cmake