# Building MySQL C++ Connector from source

Tags: c++, mysql, cygwin

I have been struggling for a few days trying to get MySQL C++ Connector to compile on Windows. I have Cygwin installed.

I run the following

```
set cc=gcc
set cxx=gcc

cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS=-xO4 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\\exports\\Connector -DMYSQL_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7"

But I get the following output:

-- Boost version: 1.61.0
-- BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS=C:/boost_1_61_0
-- You will link dynamically to the MySQL client library (set with -DMYSQLCLIENT_STATIC_LINKING=<bool>)
-- Searching for dynamic libraries with the base name(s) "libmysql"
CMake Error at FindMySQL.cmake:494 (message):
  Could not find the include dir from running "C:\\Program
  Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:218 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Chris/MySQLConnector/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I don't get why it says it can't find the include directory because I can see it in the path `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include`

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to specify a path with white space in it with cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328199/how-to-specify-a-path-with-white-space-in-it-with-cmake)

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, I've tried it with / instead of \\ and adding \ for the whitespace but it makes no diffrence